# Best way to structure code

Tags: ios, code-structure

I have a `UIView` subclass acting as an internal "notification" system, that has a label inside that displays the notification text and animates down from the top of the view and back up. I need to create a system that will create a queue of these notifications (that can be added to from anywhere within my app), and display them one by one, but wondering how I should structure it.

Should I use a singleton that manages a queue of these `UIView`s? or should there be a `UIViewController` that has a queue? Or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: The data (queue) is the only thing that needs to persist. The custom UIView class that works with this queue can be instantiated on each ViewController where you need it.

Comment: I made something kinda like that. I don't care to write a lengthy answer right now, but you can look at my implementation, especially for `JToastQueue.m` at https://github.com/JakarCo/JToast for an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually managed by a data persistence class. You want to separate data layer from view layer in order to maintain it properly. Implement the notification logic by creating a class that manages the notification data itself, in a queue, and just present said data in a view, in any viewcontroller that should display said notifications.

After you create the class that manages notification data, you can either:

1. Check inside `viewDidLoad()` if there is a notification in the queue. If true, present it.
2. Create a timer and check for the queue every couple of seconds/minutes
3. Get fancy and implement **observer pattern** so that every ViewController would subscribe to your notification manager class so that it notifies the VC that new data is available. When that happens, it will delegate through a `protocol` the presentation logic to the view controller **(Preffered)**

**EDIT:** If you go for **#3** (and you probably should), remember to use `weak` for the delegate, as you don't want leaked VCs

Comment: Excellent answer! I'm actually displaying it on the `UIApplication` keyWindow so that it is displayed over all the views. Should I present the view from the class that manages the notification data? Or should I move that to the app delegate?

Comment: I'd move it to the app delegate

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, consider marking it as accepted so other users with the same issue can find this useful too (:

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot! Done it now, thank you for your help!